# Crear otro almacen de objetos base de datos Indexeddb

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Buenas tardes,

Tengo una base de datos en IndexedDb con un almacen de objetos pero que me gustaría añadir otro almacen porque uno sería para los datos de un paciente y otro sería para las pruebas de los mismos que tenga el dni y varios campos más donde se puedan guardar valores de las pruebas.

```js
//crear objeto de la base de datos para las distintos navegadores
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var dataBase = null; //variable global

//crea la base de datos IndexedDb
function startDB() {
  dataBase = indexedDB.open("object", 1); //nombre de la base de datos y versión
  
  dataBase.onupgradeneeded = function (e) { // 
    //conector
    var active = dataBase.result;
    //creación del objeto//keyPath es la clave primaria
    var object = active.createObjectStore("people", {
      keyPath: 'id',
      autoIncrement: true
    });
    
    object.createIndex('by_name', 'name', {unique: false});
    object.createIndex('by_dni', 'dni', {unique: true});
  }
};
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tu código quedaría algo como lo siguiente:

```
//crear objeto de la base de datos para las distintos navegadores
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var dataBase = null; //variable global

//crea la base de datos IndexedDb
function startDB() {
    //nombre de la base de datos y versión
    dataBase = indexedDB.open('object', 1);

    dataBase.onupgradeneeded = function (e) { // 
        //conector
        var active = dataBase.result;

        //creación del objeto//keyPath es la clave primaria
        var storePeople = active.createObjectStore("people", {
            keyPath: 'id',
            autoIncrement: true
        });

        storePeople.createIndex('by_name', 'name', {unique: false});
        storePeople.createIndex('by_dni', 'dni', {unique: true});

        // Aqui comienza el otro almacen de datos.
        var storeTest = active.createObjectStore("test", {
            keyPath: 'id',
            autoIncrement: true
        });

        storeTest.createIndex('by_name', 'name', {unique: false});
        storeTest.createIndex('by_dni', 'dni', {unique: true});
    }
};
  <!-- función que añade nuevos registros -->     
 function addprueba() {

            var active = dataBase.result;
            var data = active.transaction(["test"], "readwrite"); 
            var object2 = data.objectStore("test");

            var request = object2.put({
                dni: document.querySelector("#dni").value,
                md: document.querySelector("#md").value,
                slv: document.querySelector("#slv").value,
                mes: document.querySelector("#mes").value,
                anyo: document.querySelector("#anyo").value
            });
       request.onerror = function (e) {
                alert(request.error.name + '\n\n' + request.error.message);
            };

            data.oncomplete = function (e) { 

                document.querySelector('#dni').value = '';
                document.querySelector('#md').value = '';
                document.querySelector('#slv').value = '';
                document.querySelector('#mes').value = '';
                document.querySelector('#anyo').value = '';
                alert('Object successfully added');
            };

        }
        <!-- Aquí recojo los datos para introducirlos en el almacén de objetos prueba -->
        <input type="text" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" />
        <input type="text" id="md" placeholder="MD" />
        <input type="text" id="slv" placeholder="sLv" />
        <input type="text" id="mes" placeholder="Mes" />
        <input type="text" id="anyo" placeholder="Año" />
        <button type="button" onclick="addprueba();">Guardar</button>
```

Quedando de la siguiente forma:

[image: Almacenes IndexedDB]

## Estructura con enfoque POO

Te recomiendo sigas una estructura para tu código enfocado a POO (Programación Orientada a Objetos), algo como lo siguiente:

```
var App = {
    requestDB: null,
    db: null,

    init: function () {
        this.requestDB = indexedDB.open('object', 1);

        this.requestDB.addEventListener(
            'upgradeneeded',
            this.onupgradeneeded.bind(this)
        );
        this.requestDB.addEventListener(
            'success',
            this.onsuccess.bind(this)
        );
    },

    onupgradeneeded: function (e) {
        this.db = this.requestDB.result;

        /* Almacenamiento: People */
        var storePeople = this.db.createObjectStore('People', {
            keyPath: 'id',
            autoIncrement: true
        });

        storePeople.createIndex('by_name', 'name', {unique: false});
        storePeople.createIndex('by_dni', 'dni', {unique: true});

        /* Almacenamiento: Test */
        var storeTest = this.db.createObjectStore('Test', {
            keyPath: 'id',
            autoIncrement: true
        });

        storeTest.createIndex('by_name', 'name', {unique: false});
        storeTest.createIndex('by_dni', 'dni', {unique: true});
    },

    onsuccess: function (e) {
        this.db = this.db || this.requestDB.result;

        /* Aquí tu código */
    }
};
```

Al final sólo llamarías `App.init()` para inicializar todo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Chofoteddy tenía algo parecido pero no estaba seguro.Lo que tengo una función para añadir datos en ese almacén pero me dice sale este error: Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found. Arriba modifico la respuesta añadiendo la función añadir y como recojo los datos.

Comment: @AaronVC las modificaciones van sobre tu código, podrías cerrar y crear otra o añadir a tu pregunta ese código para que yo modifique mi respuesta y te apoye.

Comment: Perdona @Chofoteddy no quería molestar creando varias preguntas creo que ya se donde esta el fallo.Público otra pregunta mejor.Muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: @AaronVC A mi no me molesta amigo :D sólo que es para tener un orden :D. ¿La idea principal ya se solucionó?.

Comment: Acabo de publicar la respuesta debajo.A ver como puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Como podría relacionar estos dos almacenes de objetos?

Comment: Hola @AaronVC @Chofoteddy, Sus comentarios y respuestas obvian un detalle importante: Si se trata de crear un objeto cuyo nombre ya ha sido asignado se provoca un error y eventualmente la carga abortará. Deben usar el atributo `var creados = db.objectStoreNames;` y verificar `if(!creados.contains('nombreAlmacen')){ //crear el objeto }` para asegurar el mecanismo. Por favor agréguenlo a su solución.

Comment: En la documentación existente en MDN ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Creating_or_updating_the_version_of_the_database ) dice: "Trying to create an object store with a name **that already exists** (or trying to delete an object store with a name that does not already exist) **will throw an error**. 

If the onupgradeneeded event exits successfully, the onsuccess handler of the open database request will then be triggered."

Answer (score 0):

```
function startDB() {

            dataBase = indexedDB.open("storeTest", 1);

             dataBase.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {

                var active = dataBase.result;
                var object = active.createObjectStore("people", {
                keyPath: 'id', 
                autoIncrement: true
                });

                object.createIndex('by_name', 'name', {unique: false});
                object.createIndex('by_dni', 'dni', {unique: true});

                /* Almacenamiento: Test */
                var storeTest = active.createObjectStore('test', {
                keyPath: 'id',
                autoIncrement: true
                });
                storeTest.createIndex('by_dni', 'dni', {unique: true});

            };
```

El error que tenía era al ejecutar la función startDB estaba abriendo la base de datos como object y le cambie a storeTest y si me crea los datos en ese almacén.De que manera podría abrir la base de datos para que se pueda utilizar varias funciones y poder añadir datos a ambas.

Gracias

Comment: Ya está solucionado.Tengo ya creado en la base de datos los dos almacenes de objetos.